# Spring cloud data flow 2.0.0 RELEASE

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

- When is the Spring cloud data flow local version 2.0.0 RELEASE
  projected to be out.
- I see:

  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/releases

### The latest is 1.7.3

- Is Spring cloud data flow local version 2.0.0 RELEASE the first that
  will support Spring 2.x boot apps?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the `latest` GA is from `1.7.x` which is 1.7.3.RELEASE as you mentioned.

The first **milestone** release of Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.0.0.M1 is planned for earlier next week as you can see it [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/milestone/54).